# I couldn't update user form with data from a spreadsheet when I do search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search

I can't seem to populate user form when I do search. Search field can populate the data from the spreadsheet but the rest of the fields remain blank. I am not very good with coding and had to watch a tutorial to do this.

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("User Form")
  const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName("Settings")
  const databaseWS = ss.getSheetByName("Database")

  const idCell = formWS.getRange("C3")
  const searchCell = formWS.getRange("C4")

  const fieldRange = ["C6", "C7","C8","C9","C10","C11","C12","C13","C14", 
  "C15","C16","C17","C18","C19","C20","C21","C22", 
  "C23","C24","C25","C26","C27","C28","C29","C30","C31", 
  "C32","C33","C34","C35","C36","C37","C38"]

  function saveRecord() {

  const id = idCell.getValue()
  if(id == ""){
  createNewRecord()
  return
  }

  const cellFound = databaseWS.getRange("A:A")
            .createTextFinder(id)
            .matchCase(true)
            .matchEntireCell(true)
            .findNext()
  if(!cellfound) return

  const row = cellFound.getRow()
  const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())
  fieldValues.unshift(id)
  databaseWS.getRange(row,1,1,fieldValues.length).setValues([fieldValues])
  searchCell.clearContent()
  ss.toast("id:" + id, "Changes Saved!")
  }



  function createNewRecord(){

  const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())

  const nextIDCell = settingsWS.getRange("A2")
  const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()

  fieldValues.unshift(nextID)

  databaseWS.appendRow(fieldValues)
  idCell.setValue(nextID)
  nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1)
  ss.toast("id:" + nextID, "New Record Created")

  }
  function newRecord(){
  fieldValues = fieldRange.forEach(f => formWS.getRange(f).clearContent())
  idCell.clearContent()
  searchCell.clearContent()

  }


  function deleteRecord (){
  const id = idCell.getValue()
  if(id == ""){
  return
  }

  const cellfound = databaseWS.getRange("A:A")
            .createTextFinder(id)
            .matchCase(true)
            .matchEntireCell(true)
            .findNext()
  if(!cellfound) return

  const row = cellFound.getRow()
  databaseWS.deleteRow(row)
  newRecord()
  ss.toast("id:" + id, "Record Deleted!")

  }
```

Comment: Other than newRecord() you are not writing any values to formWS.  So I'm not sure what you mean by "can't seem to populate user form when I do search".  Also it is customary to indent your code to see the coding blocks. and end each line with smicolon ";".

Comment: Sorry, I noticed this was not included: }

function search(){
const searchValue = searchCell.getValue()
const data = databaseWS.getRange("A2:AJ").getValues()
const recordsFound = data.filter(r => r[35] == searchValue)
if(recordsFound.length === 0) return

idCell.setValue(recordsFound[0][0])

fieldRange.forEach ((f,i) => formWS.getRange(f).setValue(recordsFound[0][i+1]))

}

Comment: I don't see search called anywhere in your code.